# Alternate ways of obtaining gcloud alpha compute rolling-updates list

Tags: gcloud

When executing gcloud rolling update list the following error is thrown :

```
gcloud alpha compute rolling-updates list --group some-group --zone us-east1-b

ERROR: (gcloud.alpha.compute.rolling-updates.list) Collection [replicapoolupdater.rollingUpdates] is not registered
```

Is there a way around this issue using `gcloud` ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This alpha list command was broken sometime in March. The fix for it will be coming out most likely this Wednesday with release 115.0.0.

You can also grab very old gcloud (probably a version before 99.0.0) from https://storage.cloud.google.com/cloud-sdk-release.

Note that this command group will be deprecated as soon as replacement is place, and users are discouraged from using it.

Comment: Guess that makes sense to wait for the new release. Thanks for the update !